# Is it possible to make DRM-enabled videos through FFMpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, drm

I'm using FFmpeg to convert my videos to be shown on website. Download managers however, download them and it keeps visitors away from spending more time in my website. Is it a way to use FFMpeg to generate DRM-enabled videos and/or any other ways to prevent download managers to download my videos?
FYI: I use jwplayer to play my videos.

Answer (score 2):

When people say DRM they usually are covering two things:

- encrypting a video with a key
- securely sharing this key between the server/content owner and authorised users

DRM is really about the second part and this is outside the scope of the video preparation - i.e. out side the scope of encoding and packaging etc - except that the encoder or packager also needs to know the key.

If your content is not vey high value (e.g. Hollywood movie etc) then clearkey protection is possible enough to discourage most casual or amateur downloading and copying.

With clearkey and DASH streaming format for example, you can configure the clear keys in your player itself. This is obviously not very secure (or at all secure!) but if you are just trying to discourage people it may be enough.

You can see an example of clearly config with the open source Shaka player to experiment with here:

- https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-drm-config.html

Comment: DRM is not strictly a method of encrypting video, it may has such implementation, but this includes any methods in video industry that may block unauthorized access to video content. Digital watermarking and fingerprinting are most feasible methods in such practices. If there is a p2p encryption method, still, digital content is not safe because DRM aims to block users from redistributing. Encryption, in contrast, focuses on providing safe medium to convey traffic.